# Close dialog box automatically using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The program using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'any_url'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('empty_cart_btn').click()
```

creates the following dialog box:

[image]

What is the code in the Selenium to automatically Press OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `accept()` from [selenium.webdriver.common.alert](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html#selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert.accept)

Untested code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'any_url'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('empty_cart_btn').click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present(), 'Waiting for alert timed out')

    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
    print "alert accepted"

except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```